# minecraft keeps saying this

Tags: games

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/ollie/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-1423604296267/liblwjgl64.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ollie/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-1423604296267/liblwjgl.so: /home/ollie/.minecraft/versions/1.8.8/1.8.8-natives-1423604296267/liblwjgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at ave.J(SourceFile:2539)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
```

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 15.04  plz help

Answer (score 2):

You are running on an ARM processor. It's failing to load an i386 compiled binary into memory. You will need the ARM version of that binary, if there is one, to be able to run the program.